# Safari keyboard shortcut for iCloud tabs?

Tags: safari, shortcut

Is there a keyboard shortcut for the iCloud tabs in Safari (7.0.5)? So far I have to click on the cloud button to view iCloud tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Safari 6 or newer, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> or a two finger pinch invokes the "Tab View" which includes iCloud tabs.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202525